# Center table to word doc from excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, formatting

Trying to center the table but this doesn't seem to be working. Looking for some sort of "wdtablecenter" reference.

```
Dim equip As Integer
equip = 11
Do While Sheet2.Cells(equip, 4).Value <> 0
    wdapp.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    Sheet2.Rows(equip).Copy
    wdapp.Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
    wdapp.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    equip = equip + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
```

You can fiddle with `ActiveDocument.Tables(1)` to select which tables to center.

Hope that help.

Comment: How would I define a new table though? I haven't set it as a table, so I think that part is giving me an error. Or Could I do it without defining a table.

Comment: In my hands, the first `wdapp.Selection.PasteAndFormat` creates a table with one row; each subsequent `wdapp.Selection.PasteAndFormat` adds another row to the table. Then `ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter` centers the table on the page. Without knowing what sort of data you're copying or what error you're getting, it's hard to help.