# How to automatically center a Word Table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I wrote a code to paste a Table from Excel

After the Paste, the table is aligned to the left, which prevents it from fitting inside the document.

I want to center it, which I can do manually (by clicking the "move" button and centering, or using the "Table properties" menu).
(I don't need to center the text inside the table, but really the table itself)

But I don't find the way to replicate this in VBA.

Does anyone know the way to do this?

I tried using the Paragraph Format of the range property, but it doesn't seem to have any effect

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Center table to word doc from excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600611/center-table-to-word-doc-from-excel-vba)

Comment: This method indeed works when working from the Word console (ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter) but fails when working from Excel, which I am trying to do (Docs.ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter)

Comment: `wdAlignRowCenter` is a Word enumeration. Unless you set a reference to the Word library (Tools | References) Excel won't know what that means. Alternatively, if you simply must use Late Binding (not advisable), you need to either declare it as a constant or use the value directly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdrowalignment